# How to find generators in $U(n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For e.g- in $U(10)=\{1,3,7,9\}$ are elements and $3$ & $7$ are generators but for a big group like $U(50)$ do we have to check each and every element to be generator or is there any other method to find the generators?

Comment: $U(n)$ is poor notation for this group since it more typically refers to the unitary lie group. As for the question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425462/find-all-generators-of-mathbbz-27-times?rq=1), for $U(27)$, or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997159/determine-all-the-generators-of-mathbbz-25-times?rq=1), for $U(25)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kind of ambiguous as it's been worded currently, but I assume that you're asking about the generators of $\mathrm{U}(n)$, i.e. the group of elements of $\mathbb{Z_n}$ that have a multiplicative inverse.

Sometimes a generator doesn't exist at all. In fact, when a generator exists, it's called a primitive root and there's a classification of all $n$'s for which $\mathrm{U(n)}$ is cyclic, i.e. a generator exists:

$$n=2,4,p^k, 2p^k$$

where $p$ is an odd prime number.
The number of generators, if any exists, is then $\varphi(\mathrm{U}(n))=\varphi(\varphi(n))$.

If you're looking for a constructive way to find a generator, please look [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.2139.pdf) for the case where $n=p^k$ and you already know a generator for $p^{k-1}$. In fact, if you read the article, it also talks about other cases like $n=2p^k$ as well. Therefore, it answers your question to a great deal. And also check the proofs for the classification theorem I mentioned. Some of them are constructive and can give you ideas about how to construct a primitive root. Also, take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) Wikipedia entry.

One more thing, if you find a generator of $\mathrm{U}(n)$, let's call it $g$, then every element in the group can be written as $g^i$ for some $i\in \{0,1,\cdots,\varphi(n)-1\}$. You can find other generators of the group by noting that $h=g^j$ will be a generator when $(j,\varphi(n))=1$ and therefore it suffices to find only one generator of the group because the rest can be found from there.

Comment: I know the condition for U(n) to be cyclic.. U(50) is a cyclic group and in U(50) total no of generator is 8.. 3 and it's inverse 17 are generator but do I have to check each element to be generators or is there any simple method..

Comment: @anamikakumari: If you read the last part of my answer, it exactly answers your question. There are **constructive** proofs for why $\mathrm{U}(n)$ is cyclic for $p^k$ and $2p^k$.Therefore, you can find a generator for $\mathrm{U}(n)$ and *once you have found one*, you can *obtain all of the generators of the group* by taking $g^j$ for $(j,\varphi(n))=1$.